# how do i get the rowcount of table variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i get the rowcount of table variables?

Comment: using the normal count(*) method

Comment: What do you mean by "table variables"?  Do you mean "table columns" or just "tables"?

Comment: In some old or small embedded database engines, `count(*)` is slower than just reading the row count from a meta-data system table. `count(*)` should be used when there is no performance concern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean SQL Server table variables, it's just like a normal table:

```
DECLARE @Foo TABLE
(
  foo int
);

insert into @Foo values (1);
insert into @Foo values (1);
insert into @Foo values (1);
insert into @Foo values (1);

select COUNT(*) from @Foo;
```

Comment: Please format your answer correctly. Make use of the code button **{}** to highlight code sections.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER ( ) AS 'RowCount' FROM @yourTableVariable
```

works perfect for table variables!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: This is counting the rows in a normal table, not in a table variable.